# JMeter: How to assert for each record value when reading test data from a CSV in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, soap, jmeter

I have a CSV file and I use a Loop Controller to loop through the lines from CSV file.
Now my question is how do I assert for each response for each value I get from CSV file? For example, my single HTTP request loops 5 times as there are 5 values in the CSV file, now how to loop for each iteration as I cannot assert on the HTTP request as only the first lop passes and the rest would fail.
Let me know if I'm not clear so I can post my example as images.

I have tried to assert on the HTTP request but only first sampler would pass and rest would fail because the assertion wouldn't be valid for the second iteration.

I would like each iteration to have an assertion

Comment: When you loop 5 times over the csv data the assertion would be tested on each request, one for each line in the Data file. So I think that I didn't understand the problem. Can you please add the example images?

Comment: yes that's what am asking, how would i assert on each request while in the loop, if i do a single request its easy to have an assertion, but having single request loop 5 times from csv.
My partial Req:

            <channel>${channel}</channel>
            <application>${application}</application>
            <trace>${trace}</trace>
         </nbsapd
Data Sheet:
INTERNET,AOL,Y,E
INTERNET,AOL,Y,E
INTERNET,AOL,Y,E
INTERNET,AOL,Y,E

Answer (score 0):

Not having the full details of your request, response and the CSV file it's quite hard to come up with the exact and the best configuration, however given the nature of your request I would recommend going for i.e. [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which is the most flexible way of setting custom pass/fail criteria.

The relevant code would be something like:

```
switch (vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int) {
    case 0:
        log.info('Processing iteration 1')
        if (!prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('specific value for iteration 1')) {
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
            AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('your custom failure message')
        }
        break
    case 1:
        log.info('Processing iteration 2')
        if (!prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('specific value for iteration 2')) {
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
            AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('your custom failure message')
        }
        break
    case 2:
        //etc
        break
    case 3:
        break
    case 4:
        break
}
```

where:

- `__jm__Loop Controller__idx` - a [pre-defined JMeter Variable holding current iteration number](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
- `prev` is a shorthand  for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, you can use it for accessing parent sampler response data, code, headers, metrics, etc.
- `AssertionResult` - is a shorthand for the [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) class instance, you can use it for setting the sampler result and the failure message

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)